# Understanding IO Block size

Tags: filesystem, disk

`hdparm -I /dev/sda` output:

```
Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
```

`stat` somefile output:

```
Size: 509           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

Why **IO Block** is 4096 ? Isn't it the same as physical sector size which is 512 bytes ?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer... generalization...

## In the old days, with small capacity, slow hard disk drives:

logical sector = physical sector = IO block = 512 bytes

## In current days, with high capacity, fast hard/SSD disk drives:

logical sector = physical sector = 512 bytes, IO block = 4096

Drives with IO block size of 4096 are called "Advanced Format" drives. Any read request will always read 1 block minimum (or 8 sectors). This way, sector 1 is ready to process, and sector 2-8 are ready, if need be, without a slow disk read for the next block(s). This speeds up overall data transfers, and keeps block numbers at a manageable number.

Comment: logical sector=physical sector=512B. What is IO block and how it is related to logical sector, physical sector and operating system ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: IO block is what gets transferred between drive and OS. It's a multiple of logical/physical sector size. If you need more detailed info, please Google "disk drive architecture" :-)

Comment: OK. It was helpful  +1